# Can I make the :lnext, :lprev commands continue at TOP/BOTTOM after reaching the end/beginning of the location list?

Tags: plugin-system, plugin-syntastic

The [Syntastic Plugin](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic/blob/master/doc/syntastic.txt) populates the location list with syntax error locations. If navigating these with `:lnext`, after reaching the end of the file, `Vim` raises the error `E553: No more items`. Instead, I would like it to continue at the **top** of the file, like when navigating search matches, and jump to the syntax errors starting from the beginning. How can I make this happen?